# SQL query that prevents Excel from converting long integer to scientific notation

Tags: sql, excel, xml, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

So it's been a long time since I've done anything fancy with SQL, so I'm going to do my best to explain. Please be nice, I'm trying my best here.

Basically, I'm pulling information from a database in Snowflake and putting it into a new XML file, and that data is input exactly as-written into a form email.

One of the values is an ID number that's 14 characters long (example: 12345678912345), which is stored in the database as an integer (or so I'm told), but Excel keeps automatically converting it into scientific notation. Since it's an ID number, it needs to look like an ID number, not scientific notation.

Right now, my query just selects & inputs the regular ol' value, and then we manually change it in the Excel sheet. Like literally just `SELECT ID_Number from TheThing`

One thing I thought might work is:

`SELECT CAST(ID_Number as bigint) as ID_Number`

... But it doesn't work. Most other solutions I've found don't seem to address my specific scenario of unwanted integer-to-string conversion & I'm distraught.

I'm just an intern and this might have a very obvious answer, but my fellow interns have given up on it and I need to find the answer for my own sanity. It's been a minute since I did anything fancy with SQL so please be nice to me and sorry if this is a dumb question.

Comment: That is formatting chosen for display. The internal value is still set and you can see it if you double click the cell. How are you exporting it to excel?

Answer (score 3):

In Snowflake, `BIGINT` and `INT(EGER)` are the same thing, what you want is `VARCHAR`.  As Ross mentioned in his comment, this is likely just a formatting issue within Excel.  In Excel any value can be cast as a string by including a single quote `'` at the beginning of the value, or by using the Text-to-Column feature.

If you wanted to try to format it out of Snowflake as a string, casting it might not do the trick unless you include some kind of additional string character.

To get this type of formatting out of Snowflake, you can try:

`SELECT '\'' || CAST(ID_Number AS VARCHAR) as ID_Number;`

Comment: The string formatting thing worked! We just did a # instead of a ' and it shows up great in the email. Thanks so much! I can finally sleep at night.